# Unwrap project from view for each frame automatically

Tags: rendering, animation, uv, camera

I want create animation with my cameraa moving, using "CAMERA PROJECTION" technique. But I noticed that when my camera angle change, the image become distorted. The simple solution would be render each frame and remake project from view of each object for the next frame and render again. But is there automatic way to say blender to do this automatically for each frame during the render?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for the UV project modifier.

Comment: Additionally you may need to give your mesh enough geometry subdividing it.

Comment: The "Window" Output of the Texture Coordinate Node can't solve your problem, instead of messing around with the UV? https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/cycles/nodes/types/input/texture_coordinate.html

Comment: Thanks for the informations, guys. I think I was not clear in my explanation. The mesh that I want the PROJECT FROM VIEW unwrap to be made according to the position and angle of the camera, is being used as an environment, and not as objects or elements of the scene. If there is no way to automate this process, the only solution will be to render the first frame, go to the next, select the mesh that is working as world, do the PROJECT FROM VIEW, render and repeat this process frame by frame until the end of animation of the camera.