# Project from view continuously

Tags: shaders, camera, tracking

I think this question has been asked before:

[Unwrap project from view for each frame automatically](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/192844/unwrap-project-from-view-for-each-frame-automatically)

But it was never answered so I thought maybe I'd try my luck again. If you want to project footage onto a 3d environment that matches that footage, and the camera moves, you need the virtual tracked camera to project that footage back onto the geometry continuously. Like a "Project from View" refreshes every frame.

This is possible in Nuke, wondering if with Geometry Nodes there might be a new strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Looked into it more - it seems like the "Window" output on Texture coordinates does what I wanted!